# GCE Consume Environment Variable from Java

Tags: scala, environment-variables, kubernetes, google-compute-engine

I'm creating an environment-variable with

```
 env :
        - name: GCE_ENV
          value: my-value
```

Is there a way to consume that from Java / Scala?

```
 "echo $GCE_ENV" !!
```

Did not grab it; I guess the JVM console session doesn't get it set?

Logging into the container did work

```
kubectl exec -it POD -- /bin/bash
bash-4.3$ echo $GCE_ENV
my-value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting env variable from Java is done through:

```
System.getenv("GCE_ENV")
```